# Hadoop. Reducing result to the single value

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I started learning Hadoop, and am a bit confused by MapReduce. For tasks where result natively is a list of key-value pairs everything seems clear. But I don't understand how should I solve the tasks where result is a single value (say, sum of squared input decimals, or centre of mass for input points).

On the one hand I can put all results of mapper to the same key. But as far as I understood in this case the only reducer will manage the whole set of data (calculate sum, or mean coordinates). It doesn't look like a good solution.

Another one that I can imaging is to group mapper results. Say, mapper that processed examples 0-999 will produce key equals to 0, 1000-1999 will produce key equals to 1, and so on. As far as there still will be multiple results of reducers, it will be necessary to build chain of reducers (reducing will be repeated until only one result remains). It looks much more computational effective, but a bit complicated.

I still hope that Hadoop has the off-the-shelf tool that executes superposition of reducers to maximise the efficiency of reducing the whole data to a single value. Although I failed to find one.

What is the best practise of solving the tasks where result is a single value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to reformulate your task in terms of commutative reduce you should look at [Combiners](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopMapReduce). Any way you should take a look on it, it can significantly reduce amount data to shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, you are tackling the problem from the wrong angle.

See that problem where you need to sum the squares of your input, let's assume you have many and large text input files consisting out of a number per line.

Then ideally you want to parallelize your sums in the mapper and then just sum up the sums in the reducer.

e.G:

```
map: (input "x", temporary sum "s") -> s+=(x*x)
```

At the end of map, you would emit that temporary sum of every mapper with a global key.

In the reduce stage, you basically get all the sums from your mappers and sum the sums up, note that this is fairly small (n-times a single integer, where n is the number of mappers) in relation to your huge input files and therefore a single reducer is really not a scalability bottleneck.

You want to cut down the communication cost between the mapper and the reducer, not proxy all your data to a single reducer and read through it there, that would not parallelize anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think your analysis of the specific use cases you bring up are spot on.  These use cases still fall into a rather inclusive scope of what you can do with hadoop and there are certainly other things that hadoop just wasn't designed to handle.  If I had to solve the same problem, I would follow your first approach unless I knew the data was too big, then I'd follow your two-step approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But it looks like approaches in two other answers are more convenient and efficient.